# Why are duplicate entries generated for the same label using Dashboard Reports in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, report, performance-testing

For all the labels, multiple entries are captured suffixed as 0 and 1 in the CSV file. Can you please tell me why this is happening?
[image]

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your test plan in JMeter

Open Help > Export Transactions for Report

[image: Menu Export Transactions for Report]

Then copy result in user.properties, in my case I would have:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Home Page|Page Returning 404)(-success|-failure)?$

Then run test or report and you'll only have the parent transaction.

To master all details of report generation in JMeter, read this [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/) by one of JMeter developers.